# HTML Forms submission

Tags: html, forms

I have a page refresh if a user is not logged in using sessions which works fine.

But when I submit data with a form is goes to the link for a non-logged in user to tell them to login.

I need the form once submitted to go to a different link completely

How can I do this ?

The form code is :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

The Page Refresh is :

```
if(empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']))

{
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;index.php">  

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you're trying to do without some code pasted.

Answer (score 0):

change the action attribute on the form:

```
<form action="pagetogoto.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

In `<form name="myidentifier" action="submitform.php" method="POST">`, it is the value of the 'action' attribute that determines the link where the form calls.  It is the responsibility of that page to (a) process the form data, and (b) send a reply, which may be an HTTP redirect or it might be a full page of HTML.

See [this PHP forms tutorial](http://myphpform.com/php-form-tutorial.php) for guidance.

Note, you might consider leaving out the refresh altogether.  It will erase the user's half filled form data.